# Getting immutable values from fingerprint in Android

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, fingerprint

As I understood from the developers website I can't get an image or biometric information from a scanned fingerprint in Android (for security reasons) and can only authenticate it with saved fingerprints for the user.

My question is there a way to get any kind of an immutable value using the `FingerprintManager` class ? 
Ideally this value should be created using features from the fingerprint itself.

Comment: Why you want an immutable value ? for what ?

Comment: I want to use this value for user verification. For example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there isn't support for getting such values in Android just yet.

For now Android supports just interacting with `FingerprintManager` and `CryptoObject` for authentication with saved fingerprints, maybe in the future this will change.